# yii2 - How to solve Bad Request (#400) Unable to verify your data submission?

Tags: php, yii2, bad-request

I have a controller generated by Gii. I modify the behaviors to be like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

When I fill the form and submit it, sometimes I get an error

`Bad Request (#400) Unable to verify your data submission`

But if I click on back button in my browser and re-submit again the form with the same value it will be okay an submitted successfully.

I have been searching in google and stackoverflow, many of them say that the problem is on CSRF Token. But in my layout I've put `<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>` and in my form there is `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="...">`

Anyone here can help me to solve this? And explain this why does it happen?

Comment: Do you upload any file?

Comment: No.. only textarea, input text, select dan checkbox.

Comment: csrf is time related, can you check you clocks (server and browser)?

Comment: @IvanButtinoni I no think that, In Yii2 csrf token just base on session or cookies. It do not care about time. In this case we should : 1. Check that you realy submited an csrf token. 2. Cookies or session work fine?

Comment: @IvanButtinoni time in my browser is same with time in my server.

Comment: @NgôVănThao yes, the token is submitted with the data and session work fine for login session.

Comment: what does the csrf validation do? is it good to disable it?

Answer (score 6):

add in form in view

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />
```

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue and ended up disabling csrf validation.

```
public function actionCreate() {
    Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
}
```

That seemed to do it for me.

Comment: It is a validation method to prevent cross browser attacks. If you don't have any important information in your post/get request then it's safe to disable it...

Comment: it should be
public $enableCsrfValidation = false;